# Multiple input value on an HTML form submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i want the value to be multiplied by 2.50 and add 1.95 (value*2.50)+1.95. is there any way to do this by javascript?

```
<form action="" id="formcalculate" method="post" name="formcalculate" >
    <p class="DistanceLable">Distance in miles:</p>
    <p style="position: relative; text-align: center; font-size: 11px">
        <input id="ratecalculator" style="text-align: right; width: 50px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px" type="text" value="0"/>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 3px">
        <input id="btnTotal" class="art-button"  type="button" value="Calculate"/>
    </p>
    <p id="totalcalculator" class="totalcalculator" >&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: You probably want to do these kinds of calculations on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the following two lines:

```html
<p class="DistanceLable">Distance in miles: <span id="result"></span></p>
<input id="btnTotal" class="art-button"  type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (2.50*parseFloat(document.getElementById('ratecalculator').value)+1.95).toFixed(2); " />
```

Comment: Thank you anonym, I am also glad it helped you :-)